# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 when there is no input

Tags: python

Why does this error occur when there isn't even an input yet?

```
rooms=input(int("How many rooms do you have?"))
```

How is this a value error when it doesn't even allow a value for the user to input an actual value?

Comment: You're passing the _prompt_ to `int`...

Answer (score 3):

```
rooms=input(int("How many rooms do you have?"))
             ^
```

You are getting a `ValueError` before there is an input because
you are passing your prompt to [`int()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-int-function/) which tries to convert it to `int` type before calling the `input` function.

I believe what you tried to achieve is the following:

```py
rooms=int(input("How many rooms do you have?"))
```